# How to find software path with registry key in java?

Tags: java, path, key, registry

In my code i have generated a registry key(i am successfully reading this key value ex://software//goscript/gos/9.0) with Jregistrykey and dll files . I want to get the path of installed software with this key ,How i can i do this in java.

Comment: Post your code ...

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask